# Job delegation in Gitlab runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running gitlab on private runner.Its running fine but in logs its evident that gitlab runners are delegating jobs from to another runner. How to sop this behaviour of delegation in runners?

Gitlab Configurations are as follows.

```
**config.tmol**

concurrent = 6
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "hotsXXX"
  limit = 3
  output_limit = 1000000
  request_concurrency = 3
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id = 7245
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true

[[runners]]
  name = "hostYYY"
  limit = 3
  output_limit = 1000000
  request_concurrency = 3
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id = 10183
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true



Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on **hostXXX**  f6bPaPSXY, system ID: r_HI3zVmcJqjLx
Resolving secrets

Preparing the "shell" executor

Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
stdin: is not a tty
Running on **hostYYY**...
```